# Compile Warning - ARM Cross Compiler

Tags: makefile, arm, embedded-linux, kernel-module, linux-toolchain

I have been trying to cross compile a loadable kernel module and I have been getting warning message that I would like to get help.

**Below is the warning message**

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/userid/rowboat-android/kernel'
   Building modules, stage 2.
   MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "omap_device_build" [/home/userid/myfiles/lcdc_load_device.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "omap_hwmod_lookup" [/home/userid/myfiles/lcdc_load_device.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/userid/rowboat-android/kernel'
```

Below is the Makefile

```
obj-m :=lcdc_load_device.o
lcdc_load_device-m := ../rowboat-android/kernel/arch/arm/plat-omap/omap_device.o
lcdc_load_device-m += ../rowboat-android/kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/omap_hwmod.o

ccflags-m := -I$(src)/../rowboat-android/kernel/arch/arm/plat-omap/include/plat/

KDIR := /home/userid/rowboat-android/kernel/
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
   $(MAKE) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/userid/rowboat-android/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi- -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
   $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

I am suspecting that the makefile is finding the header file for **"omap_device_build"** and **"omap_hwmod_lookup"** functions.

Appreciate your help, and thank you advance.

Comment: Is that the complete makefile? It's calling `make` again with a target that's not in your makefile (`modules`). And what was the `make` command you entered. Was it just `make`?

Comment: Yes this is the complete makefile. I entered make. Can you clarify the second statement. The rowboat-android/kernel does have a makefile. Looks like my problem might be in the KDIR variable

Comment: The default target in the makefile calls `$(MAKE)` with a target of `modules` so I wasn't sure where it would pick that target up. But that has nothing to do with the warning. Something is calling those functions and not finding them in the library.

Comment: Correct! The header files for functions "omap_device_build" and "omap_hwmod_lookup" are located in folder /rowboat-android/kernel/arch/arm/plat-omap/include/plat/. I am not sure how point to the above mentioned folder. I was hoping ccflags-m would do the trick.

Comment: I think it's picking up the headers, otherwise you'd get an error. It's saying that `/home/userid/myfiles/lcdc_load_device.ko` is referring to those symbols, but the definition isn't found. If you know what module(s) those symbols are actually defined in, then you may need to figure out if that module is being linked in.

Comment: I am wondering if KDIR is not pointing to the correct kernel that module is compiled against.

Comment: I think you have this backwards.  You don't want to be including the header that is pulling in definitions of `omap_device_build` and `omap_hwmod_lookup`.  You have referenced a *macro* that is calling the functions, but they are not `EXPORT_GPL`; or made available to modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to **mbratch** and **artless noise** for their comments

To address the **WARNINGS**, the symbols need to be exported. For the above question place

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(omap_device_build) in omap_device.c 
EXPORT_SYMBOL(omap_hwmod_lookup) in omap_hwmod.c
```

and compile the kernel. Then compile the loadable kernel module against the compiled kernel. Perform the following to verify if the symbols have been exported

```
grep omap_device_build /proc/kallsyms
or
grep omap_device_build Module.symvers
```

For more details reference the following links

- [Kernel Symbols: What's available to Your Module](http://www.linux.com/learn/linux-training/31161-the-kernel-newbie-corner-kernel-symbols-whats-available-to-your-module-what-isnt)
- [Building and Running Modules](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf)

Comments are welcome

Thank you